# Is there a way to make VS treat csproj files like the xml files they are?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For a long time I've been using work arounds to do diff's, edits, ect on csproj files. Are there some setting you can change in Visual Studio to make it so you can open file through solution explorer or enable the compare option that all other files have? If so, what/where are they?

It's not like it's impossible for me to open it in Notepad++, or go to Team Explorer so that I can diff it against the server version, but why should I have to?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Unload Project" option in the right click menu after that you are able to edit the .csproj by selecting "Edit [projectname.csproj]" in the right click menu.

after you are done editing the file you can reload the project in the same menu.

Comment: Well this may work, it's not really what I'm looking for... It's significantly more time consuming than opening the file in Notepad++. This an the other answer are good, but they're both the type of work around that I'm currently using which I would prefer to stop using.

Answer (score 1):

whenever the file is checked out, in the Pending Changes window I can right click it and do compares.  Also can view history and hold Ctrl to select any two revisions and compare between them.  Not a complete answer, but just another little tip in addition to other's answers.

Comment: +1 The OP mentions "Team Explorer" and "server version" so I don't think it unreasonable to assume he uses TFS.

Comment: We are using TFS but I can't do a compare from Solution Explorer and doing it from Team Explorer means rummaging through 5-10 folders to get to the project.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Nor did he say he wasn't using TFS.  If you think the OP was vague, why down vote me?

Comment: Sorry, missed the reference to Team Explorer. If you will make some edit, SO will let me remove the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, from the times of legacy-style projects. It is true that Visual Studio was, and still is, making it very difficult to work with legacy-style .csproj files, to the point that it is practically impossible.

Luckily, things have evolved since then, and today we mostly use sdk-style projects, which can be edited by Visual Studio without having to jump through loops and hoops, like unloading, reloading, etc.

However, there are still some things that could be better.

For example, while editing a csproj file in visual studio, I would like to be able to:

- Press the "format document" key to have the file automatically reformatted.
- Press the "toggle comment" key to have the current line (or the currently selected lines) commented-out or commented back in.
- etc.

Unfortunately, these keys do not work, because Visual Studio appears to have only a limited notion of the fact that csproj files are XML files. (Interestingly enough, it does provide some limited XML-specific syntax highlighting, and some XML-specific editing features, so it has *some* notion that they are XML files, but this notion appears to be vague, or incomplete at best. Microsoft only knows what is going on there.)

To teach Visual Studio to treat csproj files like proper XML files, do the following:

Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `File Extension`

The user interface of the dialog that pops up is quite unintuitive, (it was designed by some geeks whose primary concern was to use the smallest possible number of controls on the screen, not to give *you* a good developer experience,) so it requires instructions on how to use it.

- Make sure none of the entries are selected, so that the `Extension:` box is empty.
- In the `Extension:` box, type "`csproj`".
- In the `Editor:` drop-down list, (which probably displays something completely irrelevant, like "Microsoft Visual Basic",) select `XML (Text) Editor`.
- Click the `Add` button which is almost hidden from view all the way at the top-right corner of the dialog. This should add a new entry.
- Finally, click `OK` to dismiss the options dialog.

You are done; from now on, Visual Studio will be treating your csproj files more like XML files.